# How to execute function in C#(WPF) from windows.external using CefSharp chromium browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, chromium, cefsharp

I have a `function` in javacript

```
window.external.wrapper_print_sales_receipt(                         
 origin + that.first_order.pdf_link + '?pdf_format=sales_receipt');
```

and I have another function in C#

```
public void wrapper_print_ticket(string ticket_pdf, string stock_name)
 {
    MessageBox.Show("wrapper_print_ticket");
 }
```

I am using `CefSharp` *chromium browser* in my WPF application but the above functions are not getting called and while using *WebBrowser* control in my application the above functions get called.

The above function is written in `sealed class` X.
So how will I call it through `CefSharp` *chromium browser*?

Comment: Read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript

Comment: thanx @amaitland.But I solved it by           
"Browser.RegisterJsObject("external", new X(this));" calling it in constructor.